# Subtract two DATETIME values and get an output in the HH:MM:SS format (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I want to subtract two datetime values and the output in HH:MM:SS format.

**If the difference is more than one day, the days count needs to be added to hours.**

I have two columns: `started_at` and `ended_at`

I tried to create a new column `trip_duration`:

```
df['trip_duration'] = df['ended_at'] - df['started_at']
```

sample table:

```
| stated_at | ended_at |
| -------- | -------- |
| 2022-08-18 18:16:28+00:00   | 2022-08-18 19:20:28+00:00   |
| 2022-10-07 14:21:58+00:00   | 2022-10-07 14:41:58+00:00   |
| 2022-10-10 14:21:58+00:00   | 2022-10-11 02:21:58+00:00   |
```

Notice that the last row the dates are different. Started at 2022-10-10 and ended at 2022-10-11.

I believe I should add some conditional for when situation happens.
I mean, when the time is smaller (**02-21-58+00:00 < 14-21-58+00:00**), but it is from another day in the future.

The desirable output would be:

| trip_duration |
| --- |
| 01:04:00 |
| 00:20:00 |
| 36:00:00 |

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'started_at': ['2022-08-18 18:16:28+00:00', '2022-10-07 14:21:58+00:00', '2022-10-10 14:21:58+00:00'],
                   'ended_at': ['2022-08-18 19:20:28+00:00', '2022-10-07 14:41:58+00:00', '2022-10-11 02:21:58+00:00']})

# Convert the columns to datetime objects
df['started_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['started_at'])
df['ended_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ended_at'])

# Create a new column 'trip_duration'
df['trip_duration'] = df['ended_at'] - df['started_at']

# Extract hours, minutes, seconds and format as string
df['trip_duration'] = df['trip_duration'].apply(lambda x: x.seconds // 3600 + x.days*24)
df['trip_duration'] = df['trip_duration'].apply(lambda x: '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(x // 3600, (x % 3600) // 60, x % 60))

# Print the resulting dataframe
print(df)
```

Edit: fix the error the second df['trip_duration'] is not a `Timedelta` object.

Comment: It returns me an error at the line:  df['trip_duration'] = df['trip_duration'].apply(lambda x: x.seconds // 60) ---  the error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'seconds'

Comment: It shouldn't raise an error now.